# how to scroll an image url of scroll_page_view package flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

below is my code to genrate images with automatic scrolling images horizontal 
ListView.builder(

```
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: bannerprovider.mainbanners.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String? encodedUrl = Uri.encodeFull(
                        bannerprovider.mainbanners[index].imageUrl.toString());
                    print("encodedurl${encodedUrl}");
                    return ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.sp),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20.h,
                        width: 90.w,
                        child: ScrollPageView(
                          controller: ScrollPageController(),
                          children: [bannerprovider.mainbanners[index].imageUrl]
                              
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

error in autoscrolling horizonal and displayoing the indicator also withe url                  [bannerprovider.mainbanners[index].imageUrl] how to resolve? how to fix this issue i need to diplay an indicator to show how much image and i need automatic      scrollling and how to displayimage url.